# Populate NetLogo Chooser at Runtime

Tags: netlogo

I have two "Choosers" in NetLogo. Namely (**Category** and **Sub-Category**). The Category Chooser has values (*"Animals"* and *"Birds"*) and Sub-Category chooser has all the animals and birds in it. I want to populate the Sub-Category Chooser at run time so that

1) If "Animals" is selected in Category, the Sub-Category chooser should show only animals

2)  If "Birds" is selected in Category, the Sub-Category chooser should show only birds

Any help will be appreciated. I am beginner and learning NetLogo. Thank you

[image]

Comment: If you don't want to mess with extensions, you might consider replacing the "sub-category" chooser with a button that calls `user-one-of`.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. Since I am new can you please point me to an example from where I can understand it in detail. I have used the eXtraWidgets extension but it creates the chooser in a new tab, so I want try user-one-of method as well. Thank you again

Comment: I have figured it out Sir. Thank you so much for your comment. Really helpful for me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to download the "Goo" extension

https://github.com/NetLogo/Goo-Extension/

Alternatively there is an extension that does this and other things that is more developed:

https://github.com/CRESS-Surrey/eXtraWidgets